# How to Improve Performance of the Android Emulator

Tags: android

I'm getting started with Android development, but the emulator performance on my machine leaves much to be desired. In all fairness, my machine is not a powerhouse by any stretch of the imagination.

Short of upgrading my hardware or spending $$$, are there any good tips for improving Android emulator performance?

Comment: One thing that took me a little bit to realize is you do not need to quit the emulator and restart it to redeploy your app to it.  Which saves a huge amount of time.  But I'm assuming you already know this :)

Comment: I did, but it's solid enough advice. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [slow android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Comment: Try turning off eclipse when your are running the emulator. I don't know if it helps much but it will definitely give your emulator little more juice to squeeze! =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is testing on your own phone an option? That is a million times faster.
Also, are you "debugging" or "running" your app? If you don't need to step through code, consider running it rather than debugging it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As I'm just getting started, I haven't purchased a device yet. It looks like it will be either a new workstation or a new phone.

Comment: I would strongly recommend a phone - you don't want to rely on the emulator to test your application. The emulator is very accurate, but you won't be able to gauge performance, or test for subtle differences that might occur (or how does your app respond if you tilt your phone, use multi-touch, etc).

An older phone will do - make sure it's one that can be rooted so you can go straight to the data files in adb and look at the database.

Comment: I got to see an app, not unlike mine, running on a real device. You are spot-on @EboMike. Particularly if $$$ is my only motivator, a $100 phone costs an awful lot less than a new workstation. I'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added 2.2 to your toolbox, that will help.  Once it's started, emulated 2.2 runs a bunch faster than emulated 2.1.

I still go back and test my applications on the older OSes, but for day-to-day development 2.2 has helped a lot.