# I"m getting this on the console while running the initial counter app that comes default with flutter. How do i fix this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is most of what i get in the debug console when i run the initial flutter app that comes with flutter. This does not look normal. What should i do to fix this?

```
 Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterActivity(12595): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(12595): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(12595): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(12595): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterView(12595): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@ad2d938
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(12595): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
D/HostConnection(12595): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
I/Choreographer(12595): Skipped 913 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe02eec60: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe030ba70)
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb57f3a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe038db30)
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe02eede0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe030ba70)
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb57f3a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe038db30)
D/FlutterView(12595): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@ad2d938
D/FlutterView(12595): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@ad2d938
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb57f3a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe038db30)
D/FlutterView(12595): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@ad2d938
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglCreateContext: 0xe02eede0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe02eede0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe030ba70)
I/Choreographer(12595): Skipped 176 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb57f3a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe038db30)
D/FlutterView(12595): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@ad2d938
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglCreateContext: 0xd4b696e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd4b696e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe030ba70)
I/Choreographer(12595): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation(12595): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd4b696e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe030ba70)
Reloaded 1 of 478 libraries in 2,280ms.
```

Comment: Please update your question with the results from `flutter clean && flutter doctor`.

Comment: Theres's no issue found on flutter doctor which i ran after flutter clean. It gives the same in console when i stop the emulator and run again

Comment: Have you made any changes to the code from the starter project?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? This seem's your PC can't handle running apps on Emulator...

Comment: I'm running android emulator on mac which has 8GB or RAM. Is it not enough? @Milvintsiss

Comment: no changes at all @JesseLawson

Comment: Are you trying to emulate on too high a version of Android for your workstation? Did you accidentally set a breakpoint in your code somewhere? Have you tried to remove EVERYTHING from your starter code and just run a simple StatelessWidget that says Hello, World?

Comment: I'm emulator is pixel xl  api 29 ..and i did not make any change the code that comes originally when a new project is started..just ran it on the emulator to see if everything is working fine..@JesseLawson

Comment: What are the specs for your development machine? I believe this is a [performance of emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561075/2516576) issue.

Comment: I tried hello world and after removing the counter as well.. still the same text in console@JesseLawson .. it used to work well before ..I'm gonna try on the physical device and see if this still persists

Comment: @alex It should be enougth, if you have something to check yur PC's perfomance in real time (I don't use Mac but something like windows task manager) it will be a good idea to check it. With 8Gb of RAM you can easily run an emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you haven't touched the starter code, the fact that the skipped frames declines as you run it tells me that this is a natural byproduct of running an emulator on your machine. Generally, < 100 skipped frames in these messages can be safely ignored--it means your computer is having a hard time running the emulator in real-time.

Put your physical Android device into [debugging mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) and then use a cable to connect it, then select that device as your build target. If you run the app on your phone, do you still get skipped frames? If you are running any sort of modern Android phone, you generally will not.

The Android emulators take a lot of processing power to run. Most people [generally agree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359413/how-to-improve-performance-of-the-android-emulator) that debugging on a physical device is several times faster than debugging through an emulator.

Comment: Hot reload is 10 times faster on an Emulator... It's better to debug an app on a physical device but it's not faster...

Comment: So  i tried running on a physical device and it seems to work fine on the physical device..seems that my mac here is not able to handle the android emulator.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue once. The problem solved when I ran the application by pointing to the release mode. Please try `flutter run --release` instead of `flutter run`